# Handle SOAP exception cases with several catch blocks

Tags: c#, java, .net, exception

This(*) ObjectLockedException returned from a Java-based web service. I want to catch this specific error on .NET.

I use C#.  Can anyone suggest a method for the code below? I mean how can I make it work?

```
try{
 service.something();

}catch(ObjectLockedException exx)
{
  alert("Hey!, remove the lock");
}
catch
{
//this block is for the rest of the exceptions
}
```

(*)The Detailed Explnation OF Exception That I want to catch;
java.rmi.RemoteException: error while preparing instance QS.TYR.611; 
nested exception is: xy.zrt.ugy.business.ObjectLockedException: Could not obtain lock for QS.TYR.611

Comment: soap failures are not guaranteed to map directly into your specific platform - I suspect you'll have to settle for string matching unless there is a code or similar to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "something" operation in your service has a fault contract then there will be a detail type that contains the error information for the fault.  Look for `FaultContractAttribute` in your service interface.  Given this type, `T`, you can catch `FaultException<T>`.

If there is no fault contract, you'll have to catch `FaultException` and pick it apart.

It's unlikely that you can catch the nested exception directly... but it ultimately depends on the fault contract.